# Execute select on sqlite db using pythonic data

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have sqlite select query and can't see what is going wrong.

```
team_id, season_type, season, game_date = 'some_id', '2014-15', 'Some Season', '2015-00-00T00:00:00'

cur.execute('SELECT teams_stats_in_game.rebounds FROM teams_stats_in_game '
                        'INNER JOIN games'
                            'ON games.id = teams_stats_in_game.game_id '
                                'AND games.home_team_id = teams_stats_in_game.team_id '
                        'WHERE games.home_team_id = %s '
                            'AND games.season_type = %s '
                            'AND games.season = %s '
                            'AND games.date_est < %s '
                        'ORDER BY games.date_est DESC' % (team_id, season_type, season, game_date))
```

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
'ORDER BY games.date_est DESC' % (team_id, season_type, season, game_date))
OperationalError: near "Season": syntax error
```

Comment: You are missing space after the INNER JOIN games .

Comment: @sagi thanks, but there is another mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@sagi has a good point. I would though recommend using a *multi-line string* for the query:

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT 
        teams_stats_in_game.rebounds 
    FROM 
        teams_stats_in_game 
        INNER JOIN games 
        ON games.id = teams_stats_in_game.game_id AND 
           games.home_team_id = teams_stats_in_game.team_id
        WHERE games.home_team_id = ? AND 
              games.season_type = ? AND 
              games.season = ? AND 
              games.date_est < ? 
    ORDER BY 
        games.date_est DESC""", (team_id, season_type, season, game_date))
```

Also note that I've replaced `%s` with `?` placeholders and now passing the query parameters in the second argument to `execute()` which makes this query parameterized.

Comment: I believe that % is the wild card in SQLite, and looking at the query it would make more sense to write it as:    (‘SELECT 
        teams_stats_in_game.rebounds 
    FROM 
        teams_stats_in_game 
        INNER JOIN games 
        ON games.id = teams_stats_in_game.game_id AND 
           games.home_team_id = teams_stats_in_game.team_id
        WHERE games.home_team_id = ? AND 
              games.season_type = ? AND 
              games.season = ? AND 
              games.date_est < ?
    ORDER BY 
        games.date_est DESC""" ?’, [team_id, season_type, season, game_date])

Comment: @Tbizzness great point. Completely agree, we need a parameterized query, updated - thanks!